# Envers not creating custom revision table

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-envers

I have an app with customised Revision entity, but when I deploy, it  creates a REVINFO default one:

The Revision Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CustomRevisionEntity", catalog = "molecular")
@RevisionEntity(CustomRevisionEntityListener.class)
public class CustomRevisionEntity extends DefaultRevisionEntity {

    private String username;

    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }
}
```

Revision Entity Listener:

```
public class CustomRevisionEntityListener implements RevisionListener {

    public final static String ANONYMOUS_USERNAME = "anonymous";

    @Override
    public void newRevision(Object revisionEntity) {
        CustomRevisionEntity exampleRevEntity = (CustomRevisionEntity) revisionEntity;
        String currentUserLogin;
        if(SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().isPresent())
            currentUserLogin = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserLogin().get();
        else
            currentUserLogin = ANONYMOUS_USERNAME;
        exampleRevEntity.setUsername(currentUserLogin);
    }
```

Spring profile properties:

```
 jpa:
        database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
        database: MYSQL
        show-sql: true
        generate-ddl: true
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: update
            naming:
                physical-strategy: org.wwarn.surveyorDM.config.HibernateAuditTablesNamingStrategy
        properties:
            hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: false
            hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache: true
            hibernate.cache.use_query_cache: false
            hibernate.generate_statistics: true
            hibernate.cache.region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.jcache.JCacheRegionFactory
```

Envers version is 5.2.12

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29825746/hibernate-envers-custom-revision-entity) is not applicable because I use Spring boot and don't have .xml file with manual mappings

I really can't see that I'm doing anything different from the [official guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#envers) Any ideas here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I will leave the answer as to how I sorted this out, just for in case it can help anyone else in the same situation.

In Spring we have the option to specify the entities we want the app to scan for when it starts up, in my case I needed to specify this provided I had to import entities from other modules via maven, so when adding an entityScan such as:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = {
    "org.wwarn.malaria.server.data",
    "org.wwarn.chassis.server.data",
    "org.wwarn.surveyorDM.domain.vivax",
    "org.wwarn.surveyorDM.domain"})
```

We're telling our app to search for Entities in those packages and those packages only, my config for RevisionEntity was in config.envers, so all I had to do was add the following line to my @EntityScan and I could personalize the Revision Entity:

```
"org.wwarn.surveyorDM.config.envers"
```

Comment: I am getting an error `hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work` after doing this. any idea why it's happening?

Comment: @proprius it's hard to say with no extra information, my issue goes back two years now and applied to a very concrete situation (and a very junior developer)  I'm actually tempted to delete this question as I'm unsure it actually brings value

I would strongly suggest you to post a question and provide details of your setup, a quick google search with the error you have gives me several entries related to issues with relations